# Are Doolittle's factorizations unique?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, numerical-methods

Question in title. I know that matrix factorizations aren't unique in general, and this is when text books usually mention what types of factorizations exist, like Doolittle's or Crout's .... but are *these* then unique?

If no, how does one determine all Doolittle factorizations of a given matrix?

Comment: At first I had no clue what Doolittle's factorization is, then I checked and found that it's the LU factorization. In that case, yes, it's unique because L is a lower triangular matrix with $1$ being the element of all diagonal positions.

Comment: A more general statement is that the LDU decomposition is unique if the $D$ is diagonal and $L$ is lower triangular and $U$ is upper triangular and all diagonal entries of $U$ and $L$ are 1. Then the matrix $D$ can be multiplied with either $L$ or $U$ to give a unique decomposition where either $L$ or $U$ has all 1 on the diagonal. See Wikipedia's page on LU decomposition to see the statement of uniqueness.

Comment: The $A=LDU$ decomposition is unique if $A$ is regular, but the $PA=LU$ decomposition is not unique in general, i.e. when one can choose among several nonzero pivots.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the Doolittle factorization $A=LU$ where L is a unit lower triangular matrix is **unique** for **non-singular** matrices A.

The proof is given by the algorithm itself, since it is basically the generic algorithm for an LU decomposition but with a **fixed initial value** $ l_{11} = 1 $. In a LU decomposition that is not a Doolitle, Crout or Cholesky decomposition, the nonzero initial value may be freely chosen.

The algorithm is as follows (using forward propagation):

for $k=1,2,...,n$ do:

$\qquad$ $l_{kk} \leftarrow 1$

$\qquad$ for $j=k,k+1,...,n$ do:

$\qquad \qquad u_{kj} \leftarrow a_{kj} - \sum\limits_{s=1}^{k-1} l_{ks}u_{sj}$

$\qquad$ end

$\qquad$ for $i=k+1, k+2,...,n$ do:

$\qquad \qquad$ $\left. l_{ik} \leftarrow \left( a_{ik} - \sum\limits_{s=1}^{k-1} l_{is}u_{sk}\right) \middle/ u_{kk} \right.$

$\qquad$ end

end

This becomes Crout's decomposition if we use backward propagation instead of forward propagation.